# How to use PHP5 SoapClient::SoapClient() with client certificate?

Tags: php, soap, ssl, certificate

I need to use PHP's SoapClient with myfile-ca.crt.
How can I tell SoapClient constructor to work with client certificate (crt file) ?

I am familiar with php SoapClient, but I never needed to work with secure soap client.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4):

When constructing your SoapClient, you can pass in a configuration array as the second parameter. This array allows the options `local_cert`. The local_cert option should point to the certificate file (in my experience the absolute path was needed to get it to work).

```
$wsdl = "service.wsdl";
$cert = "c:\secure_cert\webservice.pem";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('local_cert' => $cert);
```

See also the examples at the [SoapClient manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)

Note: I've always been given .pem files; not sure if .crt is the same / works the same...?

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Of course, I tried to use it before, but I never succeed, probably becouse of relative path.

Comment: So I need make pem file from crt, dont ?
I found this way:
openssl x509 -in input.crt -out input.der -outform DER
then
openssl x509 -in input.der -inform DER -out output.pem -outform PEM

Comment: I started getting new (catched) exception:

Could not connect to host

No idea what this really means. Is there any way to get more info?

Comment: Is there anything more in the exception object itself? Do you have OpenSSL compiled in (I'm assuming you do, if you got this far)? Is there anything in your server error log (or are warnings/errors on)?

Nothing quite useful I can add here, apart from the usual pain-staking debug process, I'm afraid.

Comment: Note sure about the PEM / CRT question; the webservice supplier gave me the PEM so that's what I rolled with. They offered example code (which the above is based on), and things pretty much 'just worked', apart from the relative path issue.

Comment: I am getting this error after calling method, so connection (constructing soapClient = new SoapClient(...)) is without any exception, but calling method $soapClient->GetXMLCatalogue() throws this exception.