# Do I need an ssl certificate on my server to make SOAP requests to https://x.com?

Tags: php, soap, ssl

So I need to use the webservices of x.com

something like https://x.com:1443/services/servicex?wsdl
and I have been given a .p12 and .cert file and a passphrase...

I tried looking through the php.net pages for SoapClient but couldn't find anything...

also if anybody has good tutorials to do this kind of thing, they're welcome too...

Comment: Q: Do you need a certificate to make a purchase on Amazon.com?  If you're a *client*, just *invoking* a service, I *don't* believe you need a certificate.  If somebody will be initiating an https connection to *you*, then you *do* need a certificate.  You don't necessarily have to pay Thawte or Verisign, but you'll need a certificate.

Comment: so the .cert file I received should be enough? the confusing part to me is that both the SSL and .cert file are certificates...

Comment: Q: so the .cert file I received should be enough?  A: Yes, I believe so.  I'm sure you've seen browser warnings "Do you trust this site?".  If you said "Yes", then you imported their certificate with your browser's GUI into your browser's certificate store.  Same thing here :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use PHP5 SoapClient::SoapClient() with client certificate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346039/how-to-use-php5-soapclientsoapclient-with-client-certificate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, you don't need a SSL certificate on your server to make SOAP requests to https://x.com

But you have been given a .p12 and a .cert file, plus a passphrase. Why? Because this particular web service uses an **authentication mechanism** based on certificates. That is why you need certificate file(s) - to be able to **authenticate** and use this web service.

The most common authentication mechanism is "login" and "password", or "user" and "password" - but this is not the only way to authenticate a user. There are several other authentication methods... "API key", "policy and signature", etc... One of these several methods is the usage of a certificate.

So, repeating: you need these files you were given to **authenticate** and be able to use the web service, but NOT "to make SOAP requests to a HTTPS server."