# Soapclient with Certificate and basic Authentication to DotNet WebService

Tags: php, xml, wcf, web-services, soap-client

My mission is to develop a client to a third party's webservice, which server machine and source codes I can't access or handle. All I have is the API specifications and the addresses.
The program works fine on DevelopEnvironment without authentication, but at ProductionEnvironment it requires basic http authentication plus certificate, and then I can't even receive any answer.
They said me that I could use a self-signed certificate, so I've created one in my Server ( CentOS Apache2+PHP5.3.3 ).

The company sent me a functional DotNetServiceClient piece of code, which includes the app.config which link follows bellow.

I need some example of how to send this authentication and more the certificate in PHP SoapClient or CURL.

Here is the C# application's app.config, with fake IP and certificate:
http://pastebin.com/Jt9k6DB0

And here is my current client code:

```
/* PHP WebService Client */

$pemPath   = '/my/certificate/directory/selfsignedcertificate/thatwebservice.pem';
$pemBuffer = file_get_contents($pemPath);

$connectionParameters = array(
    'login'        => 'login',
    'password'     => 'password',
    'trace'        => TRUE,
    'encoding'     => 'UTF-8',
    'exceptions'   => TRUE,
    'cache_wsdl'   => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'local_cert'   => $pemBuffer,
    'passphrase'   => 'd3e343der434wds',
);

$theClient = new SoapClient($serverWSDLURL, $connectionParameters);
$r         = $theClient->GetBasicWorkData();
```

The answer: No answer! Only timeOut.

I've adapted the information taken from these two StackOverflow topics:

1. [How to use PHP5 SoapClient::SoapClient() with client certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346039/how-to-use-php5-soapclientsoapclient-with-client-certificate)
2. [SoapClient not sending certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187646/soapclient-not-sending-certificate)

Comment: Please review your question, the pastebin link is not working.

Comment: For local_cert, have you tried using the $pemPath instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, their production server wasn't working properly, and they've changed several settings and params.
I used simple CURL basic http authentication, and it's done.